# Powershell appcmd.exe trying to execute

Tags: powershell, appcmd

I hava to add some environment to appPools? and i tried this code:

```
$Appcmd = [System.Environment]::SystemDirectory + "\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

& $appcmd --% set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+""[name='$Task.eProto_Pool'].environmentVariables.[name='PRODUCT_NAME',value='eProto']"" /commit:apphost"
```

but $Task in second line does not work, How can I past a variable to this string? I also tried %Task%

Comment: remove `--%` if you want variable expansion in your arguments :) alternatively prepare the arguments in a separate variable and invoke `appcmd` with: `& $appcmd $arguments`

Answer (score 0):

`.eProto_Pool` is a property of `$Task`.  If you want to dereference (that is, retrieve one single property of an object) within a string, you need to wrap the string with `$()`, the subexpression operator in PowerShell.

For example, I'll make a new hashtable called `$MyString` that has two properties.

```
$MyString = @{Name = "Stephen";Value="CoolDude"}

>$MyString

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Value                          CoolDude
Name                           Stephen
```

Look what happens if I try to reference it inside a string with regular string expansion.  This is basically what you were doing in your example above.  See how it fails to work as you would expect?

```
write-host " The user $MyString.Name is a $MyString.Value"
 The user System.Collections.Hashtable.Name is a System.Collections.Hashtable.Value
```

Time to use the subexpression operator to save the day.

```
write-host " The user $($MyString.Name) is a $($MyString.Value)"
 The user Stephen is a CoolDude
```

When in doubt, subexpression it out.

### On second glance

I think it might be the percentage sign `%` which is causing you grief.  This is a shorthand for the `ForEach-Object` command in PowerShell.  Try this instead:

```
Invoke-expression "$appcmd --% set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+`"`"[name='$($Task.eProto_Pool)'].environmentVariables.[name='PRODUCT_NAME',value='eProto']`"`" /commit:apphost`""
```

This should escape the strings like you need, and also pass the parameters in, like the `eProto_Pool` property of `$Task`.

Comment: it does not work because of --% I think, anf $(Task) is not helpfull, it read $($Task) as a string not parameter

Comment: `$SourceBranch = $json.SourceBranch
$SourceBranch
$Name = $SourceBranch.split("/")[1] #ESITE-1234_test or develop
$Name
$Task = $name.split("_")[0] #ESITE-1234 or develop
$Task

$Appcmd = [System.Environment]::SystemDirectory + "\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

& $appcmd --% set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+""[name='$($Task).eProto_Pool'].environmentVariables.[name='PRODUCT_NAME',value='eProto']"" /commit:apphost
`